# format npm run output from php shell_exec()

Tags: php, logging, npm, shell-exec

I have a deployment script which runs various commands via a php `shell_exec($command)`. When running an npm run command e.g.

```
npm run dev --prefix /public/
```

The php command returns *a lot* of output. When this command is ran directly in the terminal, you see dynamic output with progress bars etc...which eventually only spans a few lines in the terminal after it's finished. This seems to get translated into a load of unreadable characters to php. A snippet of the output looks like this;

```
28% building 158/172 modules 14 active ...-row.vue?vue&type=template&id=1556f6c2&
29% building 159/172 modules 13 active ...urance/row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 159/173 modules 14 active ...-row.vue?vue&type=template&id=1556f6c2&
29% building 160/173 modules 13 active ...urance/row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 160/174 modules 14 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 161/174 modules 13 active ...urance/row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 161/175 modules 14 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 162/175 modules 13 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 162/176 modules 14 active ...-new.vue?vue&type=template&id=ffb8ad62&
29% building 163/176 modules 13 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 163/177 modules 14 active ...-new.vue?vue&type=template&id=ffb8ad62&
29% building 164/177 modules 13 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 164/178 modules 14 active ...al-add-new.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 165/178 modules 13 active ...itable-row.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 165/179 modules 14 active ...al-add-new.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 166/179 modules 13 active ...al-add-new.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
29% building 166/180 modules 14 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sv.js
29% building 166/181 modules 15 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/ss.js
29% building 166/182 modules 16 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sr.js
29% building 166/183 modules 17 active ...e/node_modules/moment/locale/sr-cyrl.js
29% building 166/184 modules 18 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sq.js
29% building 166/185 modules 19 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sl.js
29% building 166/186 modules 20 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sk.js
29% building 166/187 modules 21 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/si.js
29% building 166/188 modules 22 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/se.js
29% building 166/189 modules 23 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/sd.js
29% building 166/190 modules 24 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/ru.js
29% building 166/191 modules 25 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/ro.js
29% building 166/192 modules 26 active ...l/core/node_modules/moment/locale/pt.js
29% building 166/193 modules 27 active ...ore/node_modules/moment/locale/pt-br.js
29% building 166/194 modules 28 active ...
```

As you can see, the above is spanning only a 1% progress change, so you can pretty much multiply this output by 100 for a true representation of the quantity.

1) is it possible to trim out the large amount of square characters below from this output?
[image]

2) is it possible to reduce this output during the `shell_exec()` process **only**? I don't want to permanently change the npm config, I don't wish to change the output when running directly via the terminal.

Comment: 1: which chars do you want to trim? is not clear
2:  use the flag `--no-progress`

Comment: @Oli sorry, I didn't realise the square characters now added as an image were stripped out by SO when posting the question.

Comment: In testing, the above regex doesn't appear to modify the the output in any obvious way. In addition the `--no-progress` setting seems to only work for `npm install` which is still useful for me, but the `npm run dev` is by far the more verbose output I'd like to reduce.

Comment: can you paste a bit of the log to pastebin.com? I'll see if I can create a regex to strip weird chars

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rzDjFnfE
Sorry for the delay - here is some example output on pastebin